# Equal beta coefficients in two models

Tags: regression

I estimated two separate models, with regressors A, B, C, D, A+B, A-B

```
Y = b0 + b1(A) + b2(B) + b3(C) + b4(D) + e
Y = b0 + b1(A+B) + b2(A-B) + b3(C) + b4(D) + e
```

What is the explanation why b0, b3 and b4 are the same for the two models?

Thank you

Comment: Not only that! Also ``(b1+b2)`` and ``(b1-b2)`` based on the second model are the coefficients for A and B from the first model.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

if

$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1A + \beta_2B + \beta_3C + \beta_4D +e
$

and

$
Y = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1(A+B) + \gamma_2(A-B) + \beta_3C + \beta_4D +e = 
\gamma_0 + (\gamma_1 +\gamma_2)A + (\gamma_1 -\gamma_2)B + \beta_3C + \beta_4D +e 
$

so [under OLS assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) , we are estimating the same model (which is linear in its coefficients)

$ \gamma_0 = \beta_0, \beta_1 = \gamma_1 +\gamma_2, \beta_2 = \gamma_1 -\gamma_2, \gamma_3 = \beta_3, \gamma_4 = \beta_4 $

Comment: +1 You mentioned the key idea: *how* the coefficients are estimated must be part of the explanation. A penalized regression of those two models, for instance, might very well result in different estimates of all the coefficients.

Comment: a penalized regression would not yield the same result as it's not a linear model (in the coefficients). the same would happen if we would estimate $A^2$ which is a different model. the entire answer is based on linearity.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a linear model, thus it is linear in the variables. If you expand your second model and reparameterize it you get:

$$
Y = b_0 + (b_1+b_2)(A) + (b_1-b_2)(B) + b3(C) + b4(D) + e
$$

So you are in fact regressing on the same variables, $A, B, C$ and $D$ and only the parameter estimates for $A$ and $B$ are different.

Another way to look at this is the fact that $A+B$ and $A-B$ span the same subspace as $A$ and $B$. You can shift out any two linearly independent linear combinations of $A$ and $B$ and still get the same effect. Thus instead of looking at variables $A+B$ and $A-B$ you can define $f_1A+f_2B$ and  $f_3A+f_4B$. As long as these two variables are linearly independent you will still get the same parameter estimates for $b_0,b_3$ and $b_4$.